# Safari: When using border radius and overflow hidden to parent and the child. The border applied to child DOM element disappears

Tags: html, css, safari

When using `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` to parent and the child DOM elements. The border applied to child DOM element disappears in Safari. Other browsers work as expected.

Applying `transform:scale(1)` to child DOM works, but not sure why it works.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/amith-b/pen/JjBmQBy)

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 250px;
  padding: 1rem;
  filter: opacity(0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
/*   transform: scale(1); this solution works but why */
}
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Border applied for this button is not visible in safari</button>
</div>
```

Safari version: 16.3

- Image from Safari

[image]

- Image from Chrome

[image]

Comment: Probably a bug in their compositor. Feel free to report it at https://bugs.webkit.org/ Note that you can have the same effect without triggering the bug by setting the `opacity` property instead of `filter`. Also you can use `will-change: transform` as a trigger for the workaround (this probably forces the compositor to use another path that doesn't meets the bug).

Comment: thanks for the workaround, will be raising the bug